# Explorer is searching for content, icons fail to load and/or display properly

Tags: windows-explorer, desktop-icons

When I first open a drive or folder in the 'My Computer' window, everything displays correctly, loads fast, works fine.

In a few seconds the green loading bar appears. If I open any other folder within the same window while the loading bar is there and then navigate back to the folder where the loading bar appeared the default icon (unknown file type icon) is shown for every file and the folders often don't have their icons displayed.

1. The loading bar's appeared yet there's no thumbnail or icon to be updated. Everything else seems to be all right.

[image]

2. I opened Documents, then went back to where I was. Nothing seems to be all right.

[image]

Normally, there's one instance of explorer.exe running, but when this problem occurs, I have two instances running simultaneously. If I kill only one, and then restart explorer, the problem still occurs. Killing both instances solves the problem temporarily, but eventually the whole thing starts again.

Also, after I've navigated away from where the loading bar appeared, even the contents of the 'My Computer' folder fail to load, and nothing displays on the navigation pane either, except the 'Favorites', 'Libraries' and 'Computer' categories with small magnifying glasses hovering over them.

I couldn't manage to figure out what the problem actually is. What could be a possible solution or workaround to this problem?

Comment: First check you drive(s) with one of the health monitoring programs.  This could be your drive(s) going bad.

Comment: @cliff2310 According to HDSentinel my drives are doing perfectly well... The problem is a recent one, nothing like this has ever happened to me before.

Answer (score 0):

Try and run a SFC scan

1. Go to <kbd>**StartMenu**</kbd> and type in cmd. Run it as admin.
2. Enter `sfc.exe/scannow`
3. Wait till it is finished then reboot

To see what SFC actually did or did not do, type the following command into the command prompt, then read the test file on your deskto.

```
findstr /c:"[SR]" %windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log >%userprofile%\Desktop\sfcdetails.tx
```

Comment: The SFC didn't do its magic...

Comment: @VictorC what happened? No difference?

Comment: absolutely nothing's changed. It keeps doing the same thing over and over.